# Recent horror movie where paranormal researchers prove ghosts exist and are targeted by those very ghosts

Tags: story-identification, horror

I can't remember anything about the movie except glimpses of its trailer, which showed the paranormal researchers getting spooked by their very findings. The movie seems to be quite recent, probably after the year 2005. There was one shot where the actor is sucked in through the wall, by a whitish looking entity. Very spooky. Please tell me the name of this movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: The Apparition (2012) - Movie Poster]

You're probably looking for ["**The Apparition** (2012)"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1433822/).

> When frightening events start to occur in their home, young couple
>   Kelly and Ben discover they are being haunted by a *presence that was
>   accidentally conjured* during a university *parapsychology experiment*.
>
> The horrifying apparition *feeds on their fear* and torments them no
>   matter where they try to run.
>
> Their last hope is an expert in the supernatural, but even with his
>   help they may already be too late to save themselves from this
>   terrifying force.

Watch the [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYELiw9nvnE) to confirm.

**Note**: The movie ["**Grave Encounters 2** (2012)"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2231554/) features a similar scene, where a character gets sucked into the wall. But that's more like a turbulent vortex thingy. Also, the scene's not part of the movie [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJPteT_B7SA).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Insidious? I don't want to describe the movie because I'm afraid it will ruin the fun :x but it kinda fits your description.

Comment: At the very least, you should explain what points match up between the movie and the description in the question. As it stands, the only way for them to really figure it out is to either go read up more and be possibly spoiled, or watch the movie. If you lay out the matching points and discrepancies, they may recognize it or be able to safely confirm that it's the wrong movie without having too much spoiled.